# Specifying a callback in Matlab after any runtime error

Tags: matlab, error-handling

Is there a way to specify code to be run whenever an error occurs in Matlab?  Googling I came across RunTimeErrorFcn and daqcallback, but I believe these are specific to the Data Acquisition Toolbox.  I want something for when I just trip over a bug, like an access to an unassigned variable.  (I use a library called PsychToolbox that takes over the GPU, so I want to be able to clear its screen before returning to the command prompt.)

Comment: Is it possible, perhaps, to write a modified "dbstop" that runs some code and then dispatches to the builtin?  (Thanks for the try/catch idea, too, Jonas.)

Answer (score 5):

One trick is to use [Error Breakpoints](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-242) by issuing the command:

```
dbstop if error
```

which when enabled, causes MATLAB to enter debug mode at the point of error. You can access the same functionality from the `Debug` menu on the main toolbar.

[image: breakpoints_dialog]

Answer (score 5):

If you wrap your code in [TRY/CATCH](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/try.html) blocks, you can execute code if an error occurs, which can be customized depending on the specific error using the [MEXCEPTION](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mexception.html) object.

```
try
   % do something here
catch me
   % execute code depending on the identifier of the error
   switch me.identifier
   case 'something'
      % run code specifically for the error with identifier 'something'
   otherwise
      % display the unhandled errors; you could also report the stack in me.stack
      disp(me.message)
   end % switch
end % try/catch
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody uses GUI and wants to have a "global" error detection, than solution might look something like this...

```
function varargout = Program(varargin)
try
      gui_Singleton = 1;
      gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                         'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                         'gui_OpeningFcn', @program_OpeningFcn, ...
                         'gui_OutputFcn',  @program_OutputFcn, ...
                         'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                         'gui_Callback',   []);
      if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
          gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
      end
      if nargout
          [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
      else
          gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
      end
catch exception
      beep
      h = errordlg('Unexpected error, the program will be restarted.','Syntax      
      error','modal');
      uiwait(h)
      Program
end
```