# Errordlg for any given Matlab error

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a question about inner Matlab error management. Right now I have quite a large program with a lot of variables and functions that cumulated over my code writting and I'm 100 percent sure that I did not catch all the bugs and mistakes in the program and I don't want it to crash completely when is used by layman user. So, is there a way to display errordlg message and for example restart the program when there will be any given error directly by Matlab (for example when I forgot to declare a global variable etc.)?

Thanks for answers, Peter

Comment: In this link, you can find several approaches, but all of them imply manual interaction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010252/specifying-a-callback-in-matlab-after-any-runtime-error

Comment: I quite like dbstop fcn, but that is more for debugging by me as a programmer...Is there a way to use it for universal error message ?

Comment: dbstop will stop execution at the place where the error occurs. What feature do you want to use of dbstop?

Comment: @Jonas: Something like that dbstop will just give a program a signal to jump to some function(m-file) that will execute error message and restart of the program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crashes are good, because they force users to report bugs.

If you don't want to go that route, Matlab provides `try`-`catch`: wrap your code in a [try-catch block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-trycatch-to-handle-errors.html). If there is an error, you'll find yourself in the catch block where you can have Matlab send you an email with the error message, and restart the program if necessary.

Comment: I don't really like that...I would have to have my whole code in try-catch block...

Comment: @Calleb: so? You can catch the exception, which will give you the full stack trace, so that you can have your exception handler react properly. Alternatively, you can wrap different parts of your code in individual try-catch blocks.

Comment: ...ehm...that's quite a lot of work...try - catch is a great feature but can I inplement it in an easy way to large GUI ?

I mean like implenent it in a program header or something similar that will work for the whole program ?

Comment: @Calleb: If the GUI has been created via GUIDE, then the callbacks are already handled in a try/catch in the switchyard at the beginning of the function. Sorry, but error handling is a lot of work if you have to add it at the end.

Comment: I know now :) when I started to write this program I was a Matlab novice...

Program is partly created by GUIDE...can you describe to me a litle bit more how can I get this already handled callback ?

Comment: @Calleb: oops,sorry, I was wrong. There is no default try/catch (I guess I implemented that at some point myself in the GUI I checked). In the very first part of the GUIDE-produced .m-file, the callbacks get executed (the part where it says "do not edit"). Wrap that in try-catch, and capture the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/catch statements to respond to errors in your program.  There's more information [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/respond-to-an-exception.html).

Comment: I don't really like that...I would have to have my whole code in try-catch block...