# More verbose error messages with recursive algorithms in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, recursion, error-handling, cell-array, verbosity

**BUG: I used cell-arrays in the underlying functions, bad!**

I cannot understand why restarting Matlab result sometimes into more verbose error messages that help me to actually solve problems. Now I am trying to find a command that makes Matlab showing as much information as possible. For example the below index-exceed-dimension error is totally useless with my recursive algorithm -- this is the specific algorithm where Matlab have once revealed the specific line but now for some reason only telling the vacuously the name of the algorithm

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Dij (line 65)
        Dij_=Dij(ii,jj,[II,k],[r,q_(k)]);
```

where you can see that I am running the algorithm Dij failing on the line running the algorithm Dij again.

**How can I get more information about the error? Or how can I get inside any point in the recursive algorithm? -Linebreak and trying to get inside that point just fires the error.**

Comment: Use `dbstop if error`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010636/97160

Comment: You should give more detail on "restarting MATLAB".  Any chance your code is referring to an existing variable and failing to clear it before starting the next run?  Take another shot at explaining your precise problem, maybe with a code example?

Comment: @hhh You need no more error messages. This message is clear to me. You have problem with data structure. You are trying to use **(2^m - 1) x 1 double** or similar datastructure as input in a function **Dij** that takes input of **Galois vector**. It probably also too long. The length can maximum be **2^m - 1** and often when **m = 8**.

Comment: @hhh Exactly! You are probably using cell-arrays of type double as an input of length more than (2^8 -1) for functions that take only vectors as input. Note that Matlab's Galois vectors cannot be longer than **2^8 -1**.

Comment: @Masi Sorry you make no sense, the bug here was a **design problem**: use the ready sparse functionalities of Matlab instead of reinventing the wheel with novel cellarrays where Matlab is not originally even meant to, the debugging verbosity is very misleading and poor with cellarrays -- the original bug had nothing to do with Galois vectors or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not evident in the description where the bug is because it does not show with which tools I programmed the underlying functions: I used cellarrays and for some reason Matlab returns far worse error messages with cellarrays than with Matrices so:

> > **my genuine recommendation is avoid cellarrays and use matrices -- and if you need to play with a lot of zero cases, use the ready sparse functionalities because they have far better debugging verbosity!**

Instead of wasting too much time to debugging, choose the right tools and Matlab is excellent with Matrices and you can see it in the quality of error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Add a try catch block on your recursive algorithm, print the information you think it would be valid and then rethrow an error that will terminate your other callbacks silently.

You may use the [keyboard](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html) matlab function to check the matlab workspace as the recursive function goes on. You can choose to add it just before your error message, so it will be called every time it goes deeper in the recursive level, so that you can check what is going on, or you can add it when the error occurs (on the `catch`).

This is just a draft, it may contain errors, adapt it into your needs:

```
try
  % recursive routine
catch ext
  if strcmp(ext.identifier,'MyPackage:MyRecursiveRoutine:TerminateSilently'))
    % Do nothing
  else
    % Display useful information, you edit it to add information you think would be valid, i.e.:
    disp(ext.getReport)
    disp(yourVariable)
    % get dbstack size, to see how many recursive functions, i.e:
    theStack = dbstack;
    recursiveCalls=sum(strcmp({theStack.name},'MyRecursiveFcnName'))
    % You may even add the keyboard function here, so that you can inspect your workspace:
    keyboard
    throw(MExcept('MyPackage:MyRecursiveRoutine:TerminateSilently',''));
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `dbstop if error` before running your code to drop to the debugger exactly at the point of error.  From there you can inspect the variables, including whatever variable you've carried along to ID the level.  You can also run `dbstack` to see the full call stack.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see how the `dbstop if error` and `bstack` can help here. I can only see information that I already know `K>> dbstack
> In Dij at 65
  In D at 15
  In test_atj_7_case_3_matrix at 68`. Does Matlab have some commands to dig deeper in this point? I would solve my problem in second if I could follow the execution of `Dij(5,6,[],[])` at the point where it left the debugger.

Comment: What more information do you want?  You have a line number, you have access to the variables so you can figure out which one is out of bounds, you have the full call stack, so you know what depth of recursion you have.  If you need more info, pass it through as another parameter to your function, and then you'll have access to that.