# matlab using try-catch all throughout program (global) to report errors

Tags: matlab, try-catch

My matlab program is a multiple window programmatic GUI. I have implemented a reporting system so when an error is encountered, it calls a function I wrote, generateReport.m, which sends an e-mail with some log and state info and then continues execution.

To accomplish this I have put a try-catch block in EVERY single function. That means even creating a wrapper for my main function. Does anybody know of a way to avoid this? I.e. being able to but a global try-catch. The reason I need multiple try-catch blocks right now is because try-catch will catch errors in functions within the block, but not sub-functions of those

Example psuedo-code:

```
try:
    segmentImage
catch:
    generateReport
end
```

^-- This way an error in segment-image calls generateReport, however an error in a subfunction of segment-image won't. Optimally I would only need one try-catch (or some other statement/structure I'm not aware of) in each file.

Most of the files code one GUI window each. Some are just utility.
I wrote a similar question before: [matlab can't catch error in subfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970733/matlab-cant-catch-error-in-subfunction)

That question asked how to use the try-catch or some function-wrapper in a callback, to implement the reporting system I have now. Before I just wanted to know why I couldn't catch errors in subfunctions. I put try-catches in every subfunction to solve that.

This question is different as I'm asking is if there's another way to do this instead of putting a try-catch in every function and subfunction which is really inconvenient and doesn't look that great. Maybe a technique I don't know about to do this or a more efficient way of structuring my code to accomplish this is needed?

Example of multiple try-catches:
First the main function I run, which just wraps CSTMainWindow

```
function CeleST
try
    % Global try-catch on CeleST
    CSTMainWindow()
catch exception
    generateReport(exception)
end
```

Within CSTMainWindow: I have to put try-catch blocks on it's subfunctions. In this example given CSTProcessVideos and CSTCheckResults are programmatic GUI files

```
function processVideo(hObject,eventdata) %#ok<INUSD>
        try
            set(mainFigure,'Visible','off');
            CSTProcessVideos
            set(mainFigure,'Visible','on');
            flagConsistentButton = false;
            checkSequences
            populateFilters
        catch exception
            generateReport(exception)
        end
    end

function checkResults(hObject,eventdata) %#ok<INUSD>
    try
        set(mainFigure,'Visible','off');
        CSTCheckResults
        set(mainFigure,'Visible','on');
        flagConsistentButton = false;
        checkSequences
        populateFilters
    catch exception
        generateReport(exception)
    end
end
```

I would like to know if there's something I could do to avoid putting a try-catch on everything (I also put the try-catch blocks on subfunctions that don't contain code written in other files)

I hope my question was clear. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: In your previous question the problem where callbacks. Now you are talking about subfunctions, the trigger a catch block. Could you add a minimal example to your question demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Preliminaries.* Since your application is event-driven (i.e. performs actions by callbacks) you have at least two potential sources of errors: 1) the function that builds your GUI, and then exits, 2) every callback assigned to the active UI elements.

*The GUI builder.* Errors in building the GUI should exit the application. Which means that your function should look like

```
function main(arg1, arg2, ...)
        try
                % test your arguments
                % create the main window
                % add ui elements
                % register the callbacks
                % create backup for application state
        catch ME
                generateReport(ME);
        end;
end
```

without putting a `try`/`catch` in every helper function that is called. Since the GUI creation is faulty, the `catch` block should not attempt to restore the application to a (safe) default state, because there is no such default state to begin with.

*The callbacks.* Errors in callbacks are most likely due to wrong user input, so there **is** a way to rollback the application to the last known safe state:

```
function ui1_cbk(h, varargin)
        try
                % test your arguments
                % perform required action
                % update the backup state with the actual state
        catch ME
                generateReport(ME);
                % restore state from last good backup
                % let the user know something went wrong
        end;
end

function ui2_cbk(h, varargin)
        try
                % ...
        catch ME
                % ...
        end;
end;
```

Please note that, for UI elements that have a single callback registered to them, there is one easy way to handle all actions in a single function, thus having a single `try`/`catch` block:

```
function ui_general_cbk(h, varargin)
        try
                switch get(h, 'Tag')
                case 'Tag_ui1'
                        % test your arguments
                        % perform required action
                case 'Tag_ui2'
                        % test your arguments
                        % perform required action
                % ...
                otherwise
                        % ignore request
                end;
                % update the backup state with the actual state
        catch ME
                generateReport(ME);
                % restore state from last good backup
                % let the user know something went wrong
        end;
end
```

Of course, for this to work, your GUI builder should assign unique (and maybe suggestive) tags to all your active UI elements.

*How to generate error reports.* The `try`/`catch` block could be only at the top level of the `main` function and the callback; to see what exactly caused the exception, one can always inspect the `.stack` struct array of the `ME` object, and—for fancy exception handling—eventually the `.cause` field (which would be another `MException` object if not empty). Like this one avoids polluting all the functions with exception handling on every level.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, further illustrated by your comment, "avoids polluting the functions exception handling on every level". Thanks a lot!