# Index exceeds matrix dimentions erro in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is part of my script:

```
fid = fopen([directory '001/listing.txt'],'r');
tline = fgetl(fid);

ii = 0;
while (tline ~= -1)
    ii = ii + 1;
    year(ii) = str2num(tline(11:14));
    month(ii) = str2num(tline(15:16));
    day(ii) = str2num(tline(17:18));
    hour(ii) = str2num(tline(20:21));
    min(ii) = str2num(tline(22:23));
    sec(ii) = str2num(tline(24:25));
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

I keep getting the error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions".  Can someone help me here?

Comment: Somewhere in your text file a line is not 25 characters and thus `tline` is not 25 characters.

Comment: In your while, you can print the size of `tline` to understand where is the problem.

Comment: call `dbstop if error` then run your code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010636/97160

Comment: I think you'd be better off using `textscan` with a properly crafted format specifier.

Comment: No, using `textscan` is a bad idea if the file contains blank lines or format is not consistent in all the file (which might be one of the reasons for the error being discussed). Using `fgetl` and properly handling the lines will give a better picture of where the error is happening and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `tline` is less than 25 characters long.

My guess is that you have some blank lines in your file that doesn't cause `fgetl` to return `-1` but an empty string instead.

Put an `if` just after while to skip empty lines:

```
if (length(tline) == 0)  
    continue
end
```

If you still have problems, change the `== 0` part for `<25` to make sure all lines you process are at least 25 characters long.

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment instead?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I agree that the current answer is only of limited extent and I would have written it as a comment as well (btw rayryeng did exactly that). To make it better, an example with code could be added to demonstrate the problem and especially how it can be fixed.

Comment: I have edited it to provide a solution to the problem by checking if line is empty or shorter than 25 characters.

Comment: yes the tline is less than 25characters at one place hence i was getting the error. thanks a ton for the help guys!

Comment: So if the answer solved your question mark it as Accepted